# How to set property as PT_BINARY (and not PT_MV_LONG) when using Redemption?

Tags: outlook-redemption

**Update:**

This issue was fixed in [Redemption 5.2](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/history.htm):

> Previously, named MAPI properties in the "string" namespace specified in the DASL format ... always assumed to be of string type (PT_UNICODE or PT_STRING8).
>
> It is now possible to explicitly specify the property type, e.g. PT_LONG (=3):  `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/MyIntegerUserProperty/0x00000003`

---

I am using *Redemption 5.1* (and Outlook 2010/64) and have run into this very annoying case:

When trying to write an object of `byte[]` to a property it writes it as an `PT_MV_LONG` property, not as `PT_BINARY`.

This occurs when either using `RDOProp.Fields`:

```
RDOItem rdoItem = GetRDOItem();
// note this is typed PT_BINARY
string dasl = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{312FD430-D997-418A-8E1F-8D224FE69F5D}/MyProp/0x00000102";
byte[] data = GetSomeData();
rdoItem.Fields[dasl] = data;
```

...or when using `RDOUtils.HrSetOneProp`:

```
// this also sets MyProp, but does so as PT_MV_LONG, not PT_BINARY
RDOUtils utils = CreateUtils();
var mapiObject = rdoItem.MAPIOBJECT;
var propTag = utils.GetIDsFromNames(mapiObject,
    "{312FD430-D997-418A-8E1F-8D224FE69F5D}",
    "MyProp");
utils.HrSetOneProp(mapiObject, propTag, encoded);
```

The above code does not compile, but the types are correct.

---

Update:

With the string property the way it is above, Redemption is creating the property "MyProp/0x00000102", and not "MyProp".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet looks perfectly fine to me. I had no problem with the following script executed from OutlookSpy (I am its author - click “Script Editor” button on the OutlookSpy toolbar, paste the script, click Run). You might have to deselect the message and select it again to see the newly added property.
The second snippet does not set the property type (`PT_BINARY`).

```
dasl = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{312FD430-D997-418A-8E1F-8D224FE69F5D}/MyProp/0x00000102"
dim data(2)
data(0) = 0
data(1) = 1
data(2) = 2
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set msg = Session.GetMessageFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID)
Msg.Fields(dasl) = data
Msg.Save
```

Comment: It seems like the issue is that it string `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{312FD430-D997-418A-8E1F-8D224FE69F5D}/MyProp/0x00000102` isn't in a format understood by Redemption (5.1.0.0), and I put a few details in my lame self-answer :( -- I suppose I should get 5.2 already. Thanks for creating Redemption, btw, it's a very nice product and much less fuss then dealing with the OOM.

Comment: Yep, the ability to understand the property type ("/0x00000102") for the named properties in the "string" namespace was added in version 5.2: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/history.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

This issue was fixed in [Redemption 5.2](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/history.htm):

> Previously, named MAPI properties in the "string" namespace specified in the DASL format ... always assumed to be of string type (PT_UNICODE or PT_STRING8).
>
> It is now possible to explicitly specify the property type, e.g. PT_LONG (=3):  `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/MyIntegerUserProperty/0x00000003`

---

Well, don't I feel dumb for asking my question and then answering it... anyway, here is what seems to be happening:

Redemption (5.1.0.0) does not seem to understand a property in the form, at least in context of `RDOItem.Fields`:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{312FD430-D997-418A-8E1F-8D224FE69F5D}/MyProp/0x00000102
```

It takes everything after the property namespace as the property name, or `MyProp/0x00000102` in this case, and the tip-off was that it was creating a property with a funny name. I'm still not sure if it's possible to specify the name (not tag) *and* type in this manner with Redemption (pointers would be nice...)

The following does work, albeit it is a bit cumbersome:

```
RDOUtils utils = CreateUtils();
var mapiObject = rdoItem.MAPIOBJECT;
var propTag = utils.GetIDsFromNames(mapiObject,
    "{312FD430-D997-418A-8E1F-8D224FE69F5D}",
    "MyProp");
propTag = ((propTag >> 16) << 16) | 0x0102; // add proptype
utils.HrSetOneProp(mapiObject, propTag, byteArray);
```